# AsyncTask Copy Files

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use AsyncTask to copy some files from a folder to another folder and then list them. However, when I execute CopyandList my app just force closes. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my AsyncTask code

```
private class CopyandList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Copying Files ...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        File file;
        file = new File(Snapdes);
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            String x=(directory + list[i].getName());
            String y=(Snapdes);
            if(list[i].equals(y)){
            }else{
                RootTools.copyFile(x, y, false, true);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            File file;
            file = new File(Snapdes);
            File list[] = file.listFiles();
            ListView ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SnapList);
            List<String> SnapList;
            SnapList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++){

                SnapList.add( list[i].getName() );
                System.out.print(list[i]);

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, SnapList);
            ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

I then execute it in the main activity with

`new CopyandList().execute();`

Apologies, here is my logcat.

```
05-23 21:26:56.145: D/AndroidRuntime(24915): Shutting down VM
05-23 21:26:56.145: W/dalvikvm(24915): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41770930)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper/com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Native Method)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:119)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-23 21:26:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(24915):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: What does the LogCat say?

Comment: What is `Snapdes` ? Also it looks like you are trying to use some Root methods for copying files, does the device you are testing on have root access? if not that will likely cause a force close.

Comment: Where is `dialog` initialized? Also, the stack trace would be really helpful.

Comment: Also, I'd avoid using **System.out**; I don't know where the output would go. Use the **Log** class instead.

Comment: i think dialog = new ProgressDialog(conetxt); ????

Comment: Snapdes is a 'file' I have called for RootAccess. This code worked, before I but it into an aSyncTask activity.

Comment: @EdwardFalk The output will still be displayed in the logcat if you use `System.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the `LogCat` message its quite hard to guess the problem. Still you can try this code for Copying the file

```
private void FileMoving(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**EDIT After Adding LogCat**
It looks like in your `onPreExecute()` you are using `ProgressDialog` without initalizing it. hence the `Null` value in the LogCat

Code for That

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_Main.this, "Copying",
                "Please Wait.. ", true);

    }
```

Comment: Apologies, have added the logcat

Comment: @user2415188 Please have the a look again at the answer, Changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `dialog.setMessage("Copying Files ...");`. You need to initialize the `dialog` first.